# Getting modifiers from a MethodSymbol

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How do I get the modifiers from a particular method in a class? I'm able to get the `IMethodSymbol` but can't find any properties referring to modifiers. I need to know whether the accessibility of the method is greater than `private`.

The class itself is declared in the solution and my starting point in the analyzer is a `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext.Node` of type `MemberAccessExpressionSyntax` (`SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression`).

I was thinking I could use `SyntaxGenerator` but from the `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext` I don't know how to traverse to a `Document` or solution/workspace.

Comment: "modifiers"?  You used the right phrase afaict, use DeclaredAccessibility

Comment: Thanks, feel free to write that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The "original" C# *(access) modifier* is available in the "original" [MethodDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.methoddeclarationsyntax) from the [SyntaxTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxtree), but no longer in the [IMethodSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.imethodsymbol) retrieved via the [SemanticModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel) where that information can be read from the [ISymbol.DeclaredAccessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbol.declaredaccessibility) property which is an *enum* of type [Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.accessibility).

`DiagnosticAnalyzer` code:

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(OnMethodDeclaration, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(OnSimpleMemberAccess, SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression);
}

private static void OnMethodDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var methodDeclaration = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)context.Node; // public override async Task ExecuteAsync() => await Task.Yield();

    Debug.Assert(methodDeclaration.Modifiers.Count == 3); // public override async
    Debug.Assert(methodDeclaration.Modifiers[0].IsKind(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)); // public
    Debug.Assert(methodDeclaration.Modifiers[1].IsKind(SyntaxKind.OverrideKeyword)); // override
    Debug.Assert(methodDeclaration.Modifiers[2].IsKind(SyntaxKind.AsyncKeyword)); // async
}

private static void OnSimpleMemberAccess(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    Debug.Assert(context.Node is MemberAccessExpressionSyntax); // new Class().ExecuteAsync
    SymbolInfo info = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(context.Node);

    Debug.Assert(info.Symbol is IMethodSymbol); // Class.ExecuteAsync()
    var method = (IMethodSymbol)info.Symbol;

    Debug.Assert(method.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Public); // Public
}
```

Example code:

```cs
await new Class().ExecuteAsync();

public class Class : Base
{
    public override async Task ExecuteAsync() => await Task.Yield();
}
```